# Marshall badge re-awarded?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I've just received Marshal badge (2nd time), looking at Badge info also many users received it just a while ago. Is it a bug?

Comment: Was about to ask the same. I thought maybe the rules changed to award it for _each_ 500 since I have 1491 placing me just short of 3 Marshalls, but it looks like you have just 655 helpful flags, and so would not have earned a second yet if that were the case.

Comment: [Reported on MSE too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/somethings-wrong-with-excavating-and-some-other-badges-too).  It seems a lot of the badges that require batch queries are affected.

Comment: I just earned it for third time...

Comment: Please don't fix the bug. I got it [3 times](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=4099593) :D

Comment: Something's generally going wrong at the moment. I just got a second Excavator badge on another site. So, like @ryanyuyu said, something's affecting multiple badges.

Comment: I got this two times today alone (3 in total) http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=141172

Comment: It's not a bug.  You deserve it.  And I do too.   And I'm not giving it back.

Comment: Let's close this one. It's all around the network: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/somethings-wrong-with-excavator-and-some-other-badges-too#280023

Comment: Same here.. Was just awarded two Mashall badges, one is legit and should've been awarded a while ago and the other is not, I have 1250 helpful flags and have 3 marshall badges... Things aren't adding up.

Comment: > 14  up voted We're investigating. – Adam♦ [6 mins ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#comment908958_280023)

Comment: Me too. 2 extra free marshal badges just awarded. One's legit, had it for a while.

Comment: *♪it's raining badges....hallelujah♪*

Comment: I also got two in a row; I have three marshall badges, and 2.1K helpful flags.

Comment: Looks like things are getting cleaned up.

Comment: This is what happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/140505

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I broke some things briefly on a major optimization deployment here - you can read more about it on MSE here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/135201

Comment: So can we keep them please? :P