# Gold Badges count in profile page not same as the total number of Badge's earned

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, badges

**Dupe clarification:** This question is not an exact duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325688/marshall-badge-re-awarded) question, rather a follow-up. The other answer explains why the badges got awarded multiple times. But the badge number seems not to be recalculated up to now. For this reason I'm reporting the wrong number of badges, not that they got re-awarded earlier.

---

In my [profile page (Activity Tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603374/sandeep?tab=badges) the total number of gold badges achieved is displayed as 5, but in the badges section, only 3 gold badges are displayed.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over/280028#comment909015_280028) comment, the badge count on the usercard should have been updated long ago.

[image: Profile screenshot]

Comment: Downvotes ! Why?

Comment: No research! Why?

Comment: It is certainly caused by what happened with the badges. But it is not a duplicate IMO. I checked two other affected users and their count of gold badges is increased by 2 as well. Probably not all the caches are updated yet? According to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over/280028#comment909015_280028) it should have been updated long time ago.

Comment: Here is the *same* question on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280040/extra-number-of-gold-badges-appearing-in-profile

Comment: @RobertLongson **Research !** ***After this*** i read linked question but none of them asked about this issue (root  cause is same but errors are different). **Before asking**  i googled with "*badge count in StackOverflow profile page not same*" it returned me no related question so i asked.

Comment: @Sandeep Since this is a network wide issue - I imagine it'd be best to keep your eye on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280040/extra-number-of-gold-badges-appearing-in-profile as the devs will put updates there rather than on every single site meta asking the same question.

Comment: @Robert the bug reported here was caused by that other bug, no doubt, however fixing that other bug did not fix this one - it's a side effect. So, not duplicate and should be fixed separately.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the link. BTW this affected all the users with Marshal Badge or only some of them?

Comment: @Sandeep *I don't have unique user counts, but there were 9,102 total grants in play across all sites. 3,420 were on Stack Overflow - the rest were a batch cleanup I wasn't looking at numbers on.* - from [Nick Craver's comment on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over/280028#comment909027_280028)

Comment: This should get cleared up by a nightly job - lets see what it looks like tomorrow.

Comment: The job seems to have cleaned things up.

Comment: @Oded Yes, now its back to normal.

Comment: @Oded But, the notification is not removed for double badge awarding. Image:http://i.stack.imgur.com/p4YXN.jpg

Comment: Yeah, those are more difficult to clear up correctly.