# Duplicate notification messages for wiki edit

Tags: bug, notifications

### For Wiki Edit

I got duplicates notification when I made a [wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/info) for the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag.

[image]

As far as I understand every tab info divided in two parts

1. Usage guidance (excerpt)
2. Detailed Information (including information, resources, related tags, etc.)

But I only made changes in second part.

---

### For Badge achievement

Same thing I have observed in my achievement list, few days back while scrolling I got duplication notification for **GOLD Marshal badge**.

> by the way, when I checked my badges counts they looks good to me :)

[image]

Comment: Regarding the Marshall badge see here: [Marshall badge re-awarded?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325688/marshall-badge-re-awarded)