# I've earned a badge 6 times—is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, flag-badges

Today, I flagged my first post, hooray. Because of that, I've got the "Citizen Patrol" badge. But not once, but 6 times already, or at least: I got the notification 6 times now. A bug?

To be clear: I'm getting the notification over and over again, I only have the badge once.

[image: much citizen patrol.]

Comment: Oh, no, not [this bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325688/marshall-badge-re-awarded) again ...

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/caucus-nice-answer-badge-notification-repeats) on Meta SE.

Comment: @Glorfindel: it’s not the same as that old bug as now, it’s only the notification. I got already twenty notifications about the same badge, but the badge count didn’t change.

Comment: [8 Nice answers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LrpTI.png) so far…

Comment: same here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M6r54.png

Comment: Thanks - I was about to ask the same question. I had 22 nice answers... can't even capture that in a screen shot.

Comment: It's happening.... Apparently I just got 8 gold medals, but I'm sure I'm not the Usain Bolt of this forum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My fault. Isn't it always? We had a problem with badges failing to award last night, so I added some extra logging to capture more info when it stumbled. In the process I accidentally broke something such that it *appeared* to work, but really didn't actually do anything. Deploying the fix now. Sorry folks.

Comment: _"Isn't it always?"_ don't be too harsh on yourself. Sometimes, Nick Craver breaks stuff, too.

Comment: *'I accidentally broke something such that it appeared to work'*, That sounds like my average coding day.

Comment: I confirm I just got an Announcer badge for the same question 4 times in a row.